# Devise_invitable deletes record associated with inviter (User has_one Profile)

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have just added devise_invitable to an app with a working implementation of devise already in place.

The invitation process itself all works fine (email is sent, new user can click link and set password etc).

The problem is that the *inviter*, a `User`, has an associated `Profile`, which is deleted when the inviter hits the **'Send an invitation'** button.

Anyone have any idea why the invitation process would nuke an associated object on the inviter? I am going to try to trace this through the devise_invitable code, but it would be good to know if anyone has had this problem before, or knows where in devise's code the problem might lie.

The `User`:

```
has_one :profile, :inverse_of => :user, :dependent => :destroy
```

The `Profile`

```
belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :profile
```

Answer (score 0):

The error here is because – by default – devise_invitable's `after_invite_path_for` simply calls `after_sign_in_path_for`.

However, it does *not* pass the current user as the `resource`, which would be the case with a regular sign in.

If you override `after_sign_in_path_for` assuming it will only be called after a genuine sign in, as I did, this can be confusing.

(In my particular case: what my overridden method did was to look for the `resource`'s associated profile, and if it didn't have one it would make a new one assuming the user is logging in for the first time. When devise_invitable passed an unexpected resource, this new profile object would overwrite the existing association and the `:dependent => :destroy` callback would be triggered on the old profile object. D'oh!)